# Using CASE Statement in Stored Function MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, case, stored-functions

I am creating a stored function in MYSQL Workbench that takes a date and returns the quarter of that fiscal year. I came up with the following code script. The SQL Editor checked the statements and accepted this function has no syntax errors.

```
CREATE  FUNCTION `get_fiscal_quarter`(calendar_date DATE) RETURNS char(2) 
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
      DECLARE quart CHAR(2); 
      DECLARE quar CHAR(2);
      SELECT CASE 
          WHEN MONTH(calendar_date) IN (9,10,11) THEN  quart = 'Q1'
          WHEN MONTH(calendar_date) IN (12,1,2) THEN  quart = 'Q2'
          WHEN MONTH(calendar_date) IN (3,4,5) THEN  quart = 'Q3'
          WHEN MONTH(calendar_date) IN (6,7,8) THEN  quart = 'Q4'
          END 
     INTO quar; 
RETURN quar;
END
```

But when I tried to applying the `get_fiscal_quarter` function on a `date` value, it is returning  `NULL`. Where am I doing wrong?

I tried using the IF Statement but ran into many errors related to delimiters.

`Statement is incomplete, expecting IF`

`Statement is incomplete, expecting END`

`delimiter is not valid at this position, expecting CREATE`

I understood that MySQL Workbench script editor is automatically applying the delimiters code when I clicked the apply and so not accepting manually giving the `DELIMITER $$`. But due to this, I'm  getting this infinite loop of `statement is incomplete` syntax errors when I tried to use `;` delimiter and `END` the `CASE/IF`. I declared 2 variables to use in CASE statement to escape these errors. But didn't get the expected result.

What is the correct way to write CASE and IF statements to create the stored functions in the MySQL WorkBench? It's so confusing to figure out the bug?

Comment: Remove all `quart =`. Now your CASE calculates `quart = 'Qn'`, but `quart` is not initialized, i.e. it is NULL, and comparing returns NULL too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION `get_fiscal_quarter`(calendar_date DATE) 
RETURNS char(2) 
DETERMINISTIC
RETURN CASE WHEN MONTH(calendar_date) IN (9,10,11) THEN  'Q1'
            WHEN MONTH(calendar_date) IN (12,1,2)  THEN  'Q2'
            WHEN MONTH(calendar_date) IN (3,4,5)   THEN  'Q3'
            WHEN MONTH(calendar_date) IN (6,7,8)   THEN  'Q4'
            END;
```